# FAN Bidding Error in Flutter "No Fill & error code 3 "?

Tags: flutter, admob

i did FAN Bidding With Google Admob
& my one app is working fine with bidding
FAN Bidding not working showing error in FAN issues
'We haven't received a bid request' & in flutter debug console showing

```
I/flutter (13224): InterstitialAd failed to load: LoadAdError(code: 3, domain: com.google.android.gms.ads, message: No fill., responseInfo: ResponseInfo(responseId: sLNCYeTVGunfnsEPpr2VyAU, mediationAdapterClassName: , adapterResponses: [AdapterResponseInfo(adapterClassName: com.google.ads.mediation.facebook.FacebookAdapter, latencyMillis: 1119), description: {
I/flutter (13224):   "Adapter": "com.google.ads.mediation.facebook.FacebookAdapter",
I/flutter (13224):   "Latency": 1119,
I/flutter (13224):   "Credentials": {
I/flutter (13224):     "pubid": "227871119177837_227871835844432"
I/flutter (13224):   },
I/flutter (13224):       "Domain": "undefined",
I/flutter (13224):       "Cause": "null"
I/flutter (13224):     }
I/flutter (13224):   }
credentials: Bundle[{pubid=mypublisherid}], adError: AdError(code: 3, domain: com.google.android.gms.ads, message: No fill.))])).
```

Comment: add both FAN sdk and Mediation adapter in gradle

Comment: @YaqoobBhatti in app/build.gradle?

Comment: yes in app/build.gradle

Comment: @YaqoobBhatti but my another app working fine without doing this but before bidding i used only FAN plugin my another project so there working fine bidding

Comment: in my case in Android Studio it create issue but when I place both sdk it works fine